# Analogue of unique function that keeps order and repetition (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have data:
`x = [3,3,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1]`
I would like to have the output:
`y = [3,1,2,1]`
With unique() function I could get:
`z = [3,1,2]`

But as you see, I'm missing the 'one' in the end.
So, I tried to write a loop, but is in not doing what I though it should do.
I was expecting it to delete one of the repeated values, and looping should have ensured that only one value remained. However, the output is:
x=[3,3,1,1,2,1,1]
The loop:
    `for i=1:length(x)`
    `if x(i)==x(i+1)`
`x(i)=[];`
`end;`
`end;`
Is there a way to generate output as in y? Where is the mistake in my loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would prefer a no-loop approach -

```
y = x([1 diff(x)~=0]==1)
```

Or

```
y = x([1 abs(diff(x))]>0)
```

Or

```
y = x([1 diff(x)]~=0)
```

Comment: @user3349993 Some of it I learnt from [Luis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2586922/luis-mendo). Check out his stuffs!

Answer (score 2):

Ask your question also asks, where the mistake in your code is, here comes the answer to that. Here comes variation of your code, which works:

```
x = [3,3,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1];
for i=length(x):-1:2
    if x(i)==x(i-1)
        x(i)=[];
    end;
end;
```

1. In your loop `i` runs from 1 to `length(x)`. In the last iteration there is no `i+1` element left, as `i` already is equal to `length(x)`.
2. When deleting elements of vectors in a loop, it is a common technique to loop from the end till the beginning, not from the beginning to the end. Then your code works just fine.